# Is there a tool to compare space used by each file of a web page?

Tags: tools, bandwidth, load-time, recommendations

Is there a tool that can load a web page and compare the space used (and thus load time) by each file? For example:

[image: An example chart]

Comment: "...the space used (and _thus_ load time)" - the space used isn't the only thing that affects load time.

Comment: I was avoiding implying that the reason for such a tool would be to save disk space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), a plugin for Firefox. You may also find [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369/) useful.

Comment: The developer tools in Chrome offer similar functionality as well.

Comment: +1 for Yslow there is alos a google app like YSlow
http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

Answer (score 1):

Safari browser's [Web Inspector (accessible from the Develop menu) has a tab called Resources](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/safari_developer_guide/OptimizingYourWebsite/OptimizingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH9-SW1). In that you can find the list of resources shown in a graph by download time & file size.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/

I use this often. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, i like [View Dependencies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2214/), a Firefox extension. Not graphical, but a nice list, just a right-click away. I find Firebug a bit too heavy for what i need to do, and View Dependencies is light.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) add-on for Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) to inspect HTTP traffic, both to inspect real document sizes, but also to diagnose other network issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/) is right up your alley, though it doesn't show that nifty pie chart.